# Which is the safest way to discriminate 0 from empty string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

From user input, I receive a string which must contain numbers. `0` and empty string must be treated differently.

I've made this brief case study

```
0 == "" // true
parseInt(0) == "" // true
parseInt("") // NaN
parseInt("") == "NaN" // false
parseInt("") == NaN // false
typeof parseInt("") // "number"
```

With a bit of extra research I've made up this solution (considering `uInput` the user input)

```
function userInput(uInput){
var n = parseInt(uInput);
if (isNan(n))
// empty string
else
// 0 or number
}
```

It looks like it is able to distinguish 0 from empty string correctly in Google Chrome.

What I'd like to know is:

- Is this the best/most efficient solution?
- Is this solution compatible in any browser?
- Is this even a solution at all? Is there any way `n` can become
  something other than a number (considering `uInput` could be any kind of string)?

I wouldn't be asking this, but since empty string and 0 are treated the same (?!) I don't know to which other holes is my code potentialy exposed.

Comment: `if(parseInt(uInput)==0&&uInput.length()==0){then it isnt 0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
var nmbr = parseInt(uInput, 10);
if (!isNaN(nmbr)) {
    // Yay, valid input!
} else {
    // Ups, weird input...
}
```

This seems the simplest and most correct answer, because [`parseInt` only returns an integer or `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: This will say "3434 String" is valid input which is not  :(

Comment: I was assuming @Saturnix wanted to just drop the string after the first numbers... `parseInt('3434 String'` will return **3434**, which seems fine to me. But, if you want to be more rigorous, you could use `Number(uInput)` to match with `parseInt(uInput, 10)` result, and check their differences.

Comment: "3434 String" to become 3434 is ok to me - I just wanted to make sure that the final value I get is a number and not a string. I didn't tought about checking the possible return values of parseInt(). Since you proven me there can only be 2 (number or NaN) I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the `===`, try it like: `0 === ""` // false

The difference about them and about type conversions read:
[Q: Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/949346)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even a solution at all? Is there any way n can become something other than a number?

Yes. `parseInt` only does consider the first, integer part of the string when parsing it. It ignores the rest, so `"12.34 oops"` will still validate as `12`.

> I receive a string which must contain numbers

You can use a [simple regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to test that:

```
/^\d+$/.test(uInput)
```

It will yield `true` for strings that consists of only (and at least one) digits, and `false` for anything else (non-numeric and empty strings).

Answer (score 0):

Create your own test, you do like a million try for each and retrieve the time it takes.

For browser compatibility, I guess simple operation should be alike.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function validate(uInput){
    var regEx = /^[1-9]{1}[\d]*$/;
    if (regEx.test(uInput))
        alert(uInput + " is a valid number.");
    else
        alert(uInput + " is not valid number.");

    var validNumber = parseInt(uInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0 == "" // true
```

because of == which does a type coercion first:

```
0 == false, "" == false so false == false.
```

you should be using ===, where

```
0 === "" // false
```

without type coercion.